# Symfony2 autoload user from Session

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to symfony and I'm trying to build a login system.
I have a very simple relation to store the user

```
user(id:PK, name:string)
```

After a user has logged in, I store userId in his session like this

```
$session = new Session();
$session->set('userId', $user->getId());
```

I later use userId to fetch the user from the database and display personalized content. This is the code I have in my controller

```
$session = new Session();
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->find($session->get('userId'));
```

How do I tell symfony to automatically fetch the user at every request, without writing the code myself for every controller?

Comment: You need to be more specific here since simply saying "Symfony" isn't very specific. Depends on many things including the way you configured the Framework and what your application does. Regarding the login system, it seems that you managed to create the login screen in which case I would recommend adding what you need for the user in that functionality.

Comment: I've edited the question. I hope it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has a pretty solid [security system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html), you should implement your login system it's way. You can find information on how to integrate the traditional login system with a database in the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html).

If you are authenticating your users this way, fetching the current user becomes easy:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Or, if you're inside a controller action:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

There's also the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/), which gives you some great tools to handle common user management at your system.

Comment: My approach was definitely too much convoluted. Configuring a Symfony Firewall is definitely the right answer.